Usage of Cv vs Cp in this question
I don’t understand why we use $C_{V}$ here rather than $C_{P}$ to get the answer.
mixture of hydrogen gas and the standard composition of air at 25°C with a total pressure of 1 atm, is exploded in a closed rigid vessel. If the combustion occurs in an adiabatic system, given that:
(i) $C_{V}$ (N2) = $\pu{8.3 cal K-1 mol-1}$
(ii) $C_{P}$ (H2O)= $\pu{11.3 cal K-1 mol-1}$
(iii)$\Delta_\mathrm{} H$ H2O(g)= -57.8 Kcal (Take air as 80% N2 , 20% O2 by volume)
What will be the maximum temperature attained if the process occurs in adiabatic container.
(A) 2940 K
(C) 1900 K
(B) 2665 K
(D) 298 K
As $\Delta_\mathrm{r} H$ is given shouldn’t I use $C_{P}$ rather than $C_{V}$

Ever wondered why $c_V$ is called $c_V$? Why V, of all letters? Not A, not B, not C... but V? Isn't that strange?

You're supposed to know how Cp and Cv diffeR for ideal gases. Then you can use Cv as expected.

"exploded in a closed rigid vessel."

For your reaction in an adiabatic rigid container, $$\Delta U=\Delta U_{reaction}+[n_{nitrogen}Cv_{nitrogen}+n_{water}Cv_{water}](T-T_0)=0$$where $$\Delta U_{reaction}+\Delta (PV)_{reaction}=\Delta H_{reaction}$$and where $$\Delta (PV)_{reaction}=(\Delta n)RT_0$$with $\Delta n$ representing the increase in the number of moles of gas due to the reaction.
